# Creating 28 checkboxes with a common name and different values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

There are 28 check boxes that are given a common name and have different values:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="Schedules" id="checkbox1" value="1">
```

In controller in post action:

```cs
public ActionResult Create(SubscriptionPlanCreateViewModel subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel, FormCollection Form)
{
    string[] AllStrings = Form["Schedules"].Split(',');
    foreach (string item in AllStrings)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(item);
        if (value == 1)
        {
            subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel.Timeschedule = "OneTime";
        }
    }
}
```

By using this code I need to use 28 `if` conditions. How can I reduce the code size?

Comment: Are all the `if` conditions trying to set the `Timeschedule` property? Or are they all setting different properties on your view model? Also, do you have any control over how the view is generated, or are you restricted to just changing the controller code?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No value==1 for time schedule for serp and passes value "onetime" to  Timeschedule then value==2 passes value="Weekly" to timeschedule etc

Comment: So what if both checkbox 1 and 2 are selected?

Comment: if both the value 1 & 2 are selected the timeschedule is appended with value of 2 if (value == 1)
                {
                    subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel.SerpRankingSchedule = "OneTime";
                }

                if (value == 2)
                {
                    subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel.SerpRankingSchedule = (subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel.SerpRankingSchedule == null || subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel.SerpRankingSchedule == "") ? "Weekly" : subscriptionPlanCreateViewModel.SerpRankingSchedule + " | Weekly"; }

Comment: the first 3 values are for  SerpRankingSchedule then the next 3 values are for Reports schedule etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the checkboxes like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Timeschedule" id="checkbox1" value="OneTime">
<input type="checkbox" name="Timeschedule" id="checkbox2" value="Weekly">
```

and in the controller action the values from multiple checkboxes can be retrieved by using this method

```
string[] AllStrings = Form["Timeschedule"].Split(',');
```

or

```
string[] AllStrings = Request["Timeschedule[]"].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that what you really need to do is change the view code. For example, if you do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Timeschedule" id="checkbox1" value="OneTime">
<input type="checkbox" name="Timeschedule" id="checkbox2" value="Weekly">
```

That will automatically bind to the `Timeschedule` property on your `SubscriptionPlanCreateViewModel`. However, if the user selects multiple checkboxes, the values will probably come across as comma-separated. You can *either* make `Timeschedule` an array (which would probably better represent what you're doing from a data perspective) or you can simply replace the commas with " | " to produce the string you say you want in your comments.